# Configuring the Google App Engine SDK for offline use

Tags: python, google-app-engine, networking

How can I configure the Google App Engine SDK to run the local development server without requiring a network connection? I've tried removing `~/.appcfg_nag` and setting `--skip_sdk_update_check` at runtime, but it still fails with the following error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

EDIT: Here's the complete command and error output:

```
$ dev_appserver.py helloworld/
INFO     2012-02-20 20:00:19,712 py_zipimport.py:148] zipimporter('/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-fat.egg', 'MySQLdb/')
WARNING  2012-02-20 20:00:19,784 rdbms_mysqldb.py:94] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
Warning: You are using a Python runtime (2.6) that is more recent than the production runtime environment (2.5). Your application may use features that are not available in the production environment and may not work correctly when deployed to production.
INFO     2012-02-20 20:00:19,859 appengine_rpc.py:159] Server: appengine.google.com
WARNING  2012-02-20 20:00:19,874 dev_appserver.py:3396] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 99, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 95, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 692, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 656, in main
    persist_logs=persist_logs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3594, in CreateServer
    server = HTTPServerWithScheduler((serve_address, port), handler_class)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3622, in __init__
    request_handler_class)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 400, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 411, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: Is your "Run configuration" for that specific app has "Run built in-server" checked?

![Run configurations in Eclipse][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/T0dGq.jpg

Comment: This sounds like it might be an issue binding to a local port or hostname, as opposed to actually trying to reach the WAN.  (Failing to check for SDK updates does not result in a fatal error.)  How are you starting your server?  Is this the Python or Java SDK?

Comment: @vishal.biyani I'm not using Eclipse--I'm running the dev server from the command line with `$ dev_appserver.py helloworld/`.

@DanSanderson Python.

Comment: Can you paste the complete command, including the arguments you are passing

Comment: Sure--I just edited the question to include the full command and error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is to bind to 127.0.0.1, which is resolved to "localhost" by looking it up on /etc/hosts (or vice-versa). Try forcing it to bind to 127.0.0.1:8080 by starting it as "dev_appserver.py helloworld -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8080" or bind it to all local addresses with "dev_appserver.py helloworld -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8080" and see what happens.

Comment: dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -a 127.0.0.1

Comment: You need to use `--host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080` to achieve that. I had the same error "nodename nor servname provided, or not known" somewhere else. How did you fix it?